# Pass array from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, web-development-server

I'm trying to create a carousel so I can click through each element in `csv` file:

In a `routes/index.js` file I'm reading a `csv` file with film data in an `array`, and then loading this into the `index.ejs` file when its opened:

```
//get request - open index.ejs page
router.get(['/', '/index', '/discover', '/home'], function (req, res) {

  //read film data into array for frontend
  const films = [];
  fs.createReadStream('film_data.csv')
    .pipe(csvParser())
    .on('data', (row) => {
      films.push(row);
    })
   .on('end', () => {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express', session: { email:req.cookies.sessionEmail }, films: films });
    })
});
```

In the `index.ejs` file I am trying to create a carousel so I click next or previous and show the next film title in the array:

```HTML
<!-- Film carousel -->
<div class="carousel" id="film-carousel" data='<%- films %>'>
  <button id="prev-btn">Previous</button>
  <div id="current-film">
    <!-- films displayed here from scripts/index.js -->
  </div>
  <button id="next-btn">Next</button>
</div>

<!-- END film carousel -->
```

The functionality for this is handled in the `scripts/index.js` file, however I don't know how to put the array from the `.ejs` file to the `.js` file so I can implement this, does anyone know how to do this?

This is my scripts/index.js file:

```
window.onload = function () {
  const currentFilmElement = document.getElementById('current-film');
  const prevButton         = document.getElementById('prev-btn');
  const nextButton         = document.getElementById('next-btn');

  var films        = document.getElementById('film-carousel').getAttribute('data');
  var currentIndex = 0;

  // Initial update
  updateFilm();

  // Function to update the displayed film
  function updateFilm() {
    currentFilmElement.innerHTML = `<strong>Title:</strong> ${films[currentIndex].primaryTitle} <br><p></p>`;
  }

  // Event listener for the previous button
  prevButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1);
    if(currentIndex < 0) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
    updateFilm();
  });

  // Event listener for the next button
  nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1);
    updateFilm();
  });
};
```

Currently I am trying to pass it as a data attribute which i am accessing in the `scipts/index.js` file, but when I try to use the array here I get errors, and rather than seeing film data it is in the format `[object object]`, `[object object]` etc.
Can anyone advise?

Comment: check out this link it might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156490/pass-data-from-node-express-to-front-end-javascript

Comment: Not sure about size limit, but it is clear - you set object, data are transfering as string (default films.toString() conversion). JSON.stringify(films) on server and JSON.parse(films) on client may help... Or easier could be to put film_data.csv content into an invisible textarea in the page and just read content.

Comment: I've tried using JSON.stringify but it changes the structure of the data when it is parsed again

Comment: Using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse should work, can you show how it gives you an error?